# New onClickListener with NullPointerException (Android)

Tags: java, android

I create a few textViews with onClickListeners at run time.

But I get a `NullPointer..`.
I think the reason is the View, he dosnt know where the textView should be.

How could I solve this?

The interesting lines of the class `ShowSomething`:

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Toast.makeText(ShowSomething.this, textView.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    layout.addView(t);
```

Full class `ShowSomething`:

```
public class ShowSomething extends Activity {

    public void showData(final String[][] array, final int i, int j, LinearLayout layout, final TextView t, TextView t2, int color) {
        String Text = null;
        int size = 12;
        int top = 0;
        int bot = 0;

        if (j == 0) {
            size = 14;
            Text = array[j][i];
            top = 5;
            bot = 0;

        }
        if (j == 1) {
            size = 10;
            Text = "  " + array[j][i];
            top = 5;
            bot = 5;
        }
        t.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, size);
        t.setTextColor(color);
        t.setPadding(0, top, 0, bot);
        t.setClickable(false);
        t.setText(Text);
        t.setId(j + i);
        t.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(ShowSomething.this, t.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        layout.addView(t);
    }
}
```

The interesting lines of the class `ProjectsActivity`:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_projects);
    int j = 0;
    //result    
    for (i = 0; i < array[0].length; i++) {
        while (j <2) {
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
            final TextView t = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            final TextView t2 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            ShowSomething.showData(array, i, j, layout, t, t2, color);
```

Full class `ProjectsActivity`:

```
public class ProjectsActivity extends Activity {
public String[][] array = null;
public int i = 0;
int color;
ShowSomething show = new ShowSomething();
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_projects);

    int j = 0;

    array = Connect.printJobList();

    for (i = 0; i < array[0].length; i++) {
        while (j < 2) {
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
            final TextView t = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            final TextView t2 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

            if (j == 0){    
                color = getResources().getColor(R.color.Project1);
            }
            if (j == 1){
                color = getResources().getColor(R.color.Project2);
            }

            show.showData(array, i, j, layout, t, t2, color);
            if (j == 1){
                t2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1));
                t2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Line));
                layout.addView(t2);
            }
            j++;
        }
        j = 0;
    }       
}
```

}

`LogCat`:

```
03-26 08:19:38.294: D/AndroidRuntime(1991): Shutting down VM
03-26 08:19:38.294: W/dalvikvm(1991):       threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
03-26 08:19:38.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1991): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 08:19:38.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1991): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-26 08:19:38.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
03-26 08:19:38.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at de.xcom.mobilenav.ShowSomething$1.onClick(ShowSomething.java:47)
03-26 08:19:38.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
03-26 08:19:38.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
03-26 08:19:38.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
03-26 08:19:38.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-26 08:19:38.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-26 08:19:38.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-26 08:19:38.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 08:19:38.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-26 08:19:38.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-26 08:19:38.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-26 08:19:38.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Line 47 of `ShowSomething`: (ignore the comments)

```
43 public void onClick(View v) { 
44 //Intent intent = new Intent(ShowSomething.this, ProjectDetailActivity.class); 
45 //intent.putExtra("Project", array[0][i]); 
46   
47 //startActivity(intent); 
48 
49 Toast.makeText(ShowSomething.this, t.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Changed the class `ShowSomething`:

```
public class ShowSomething {
.
.
.   t.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ShowSomething.this, ProjectDetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Project", array[0][i]);

        startActivity(intent);

        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , t.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

But now I get an error: The contructor Intent(ShowSomething, Class) is undefined...

Comment: Please post logcat. Without it it will be difficult to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Where is Activity Life cycle methods and SetContentView And method callings..You need to first look at this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: where is oncreate() and findviewbyid?

Comment: You need to use `TextView t = new TextView(this);`

Comment: First step in fixing null pointer exceptions is to figure out which variable is null. Check the log to see what line is generating the exception and then see what variables are on that line, and check which of them is null at the time.

Comment: change `getApplicationContext()` to `ActivityName.this` may be thats the problem

Comment: Stacktrace says you're calling `setContentView()` in an `onClick()` under `ShowSomething` but the code you posted doesn't agree with that. The exception could occur e.g. if the activity is not properly initialized (in essence, it has no `Window`).

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tat Ratatouille It dosnt solve the problem...

Comment: ShowSomething.java:47 what is at this line number ?

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tat Ratatouille added these lines to my first post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have a problem with the context, first argument of the .makeText. You need to check in which line you have the NPE. Look at the LogCat window, you will see something like:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at yourpackagename.ShowSomething.showData(ShowSomething.java:123)

Then you will know where you have the NPE, or just ask further.

After Edit:

So you're trying to start an Intent now withou any context (ShowSomething isn't extendig activity right now)

You need to pass the Context to your ShowSomething class, maybe in constructor, and then use it:

```
public class ShowSomething {
...
Context mContext;

public ShowSomething(Context context){
   this.mContext=context;
}
```

calling:     mContext.startActivity(intent); in the onClickListener

Creating your ShowSomething object then in your main activity:

> ShowSomething myClass = new ShowSomething(getApplicationContext());

Comment: I also had to insert this: intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); ....but yeah... it works now, many many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
ShowSomething show = new ShowSomething();
```

You cannot instantiate activities with `new`.

Looks like `ShowSomething` should not be an activity at all. You can pass a `Context` to it as a method argument, for example.

To pass data from an activity to another, use intents. See [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Toast.makeText(ShowSomething.this, t.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Are you sure that `t != null ?`

Comment: it isnt null... test before Toast=>  if (t == null){

       Log.d("Test", "hello world");
      }

Comment: There is something weird with your approach, why are you extending Activity for ShowSomething? Maybe you should use it with a utility class but extend Activity and call new Activity()... is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

First you have to create the object for the textview like this:

```
TextView t=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
```

Comment: How?
At this time i dont know the ID, because it does not exists.

Comment: Create the object for the textview in oncreate() method,,,,, and try again,,,,,,,,,,,